# Iterating format % placeholders one by one

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got an NSAttributedString that looks like

"Somestring **bold %@ template %f %d** blah blah blah"

I want to be able to replace the format template parts just like in [NSString stringWithFormat:...] but keeping the styling, so that the replaced strings match the styling around them (all bold in my example above).

Is there a way to iterate through each format % placeholder one by one so I can use a list of arguments to fill the string?

I don't want to build my own % implementation because I know theres a million and one different formats.

Or is there an easier solution that I'm overlooking?

Edit:
I'll explain a bit of the complete solution I'm solving:

To make it possible for my team to attribute localized strings I've already got a way to write

```
"key"="test //italic %@// **bold** __underline %d__";
```

If a specifier is between attributed tags I want that part to be attributed. Currently I can create an attributed string as seen above, the next part is to take care of the specifiers left over.

I'm doing it in the order of *Parse attributes -> Apply arguments*..., I could easily solve it the other way but I don't want format arguments to mess with the attributes

Comment: Yes; see `va_start()`, `va_next()` and `va_end()`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm referring to the placeholder percentage tokens, not the arguments themselves. If I can determine where each percentage token is, then I can iterate over the arguments list and replace the tokens in the attributed string and keep the attributes (bold, italic etc etc)

Comment: Finding each of the `%` specifiers is easy enough with an `NSScanner`, but I'm not quite clear on what you want to do. What do you mean by "I don't want to build my own % implementation..."?

Comment: @JoshCaswell there's a lot, so I'd prefer if there was something built in, here's some valid formats: %@, %i, %d, %f, %0.2f, %li, %2%@, %2i, %5.2f, %x, %s, %lu... there's probably thousands more

Comment: Oh, sure, I gotcha. You don't want to have to parse the specifiers. That makes sense.

Comment: Do you know how many arguments you have?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I can iterate over the arguments, although another issue I'm having is having arguments of multiple types, like NSStrings, ints, etc etc in the same argument list similar to [NSString stringWithFormat:]

Comment: So why don't you simply use a regular expression to find all %W occurrences which you then can replace?

Comment: objective-conly support limit set of formatters. (Refer : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) So may be you can write  a custom parser.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to avoid the problem. How is it that you've come to have an attributed format string? Why is it attributed? How was it determined what ranges to apply which attributes to? Could that logic be applied to the post-formatting string?

Comment: @KenThomases I'll explain a bit of the complete solution I'm solving: To make it possible for my team to attribute localized strings I've already got a way to write "key"="test //italic %@// ****bold****" etc etc, if a specifier is between attributed tags I want that part to be attributed. Currently I can create an attributed string as seen in my first post, the next part is to take care of the specifiers left over. I'm doing it in the order of Parse attributes -> Apply arguments..., I could easily solve it the other way but I don't want format arguments to mess with the attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big thanks to @Rick for pointing me in the right direction.

His post recommends first going over the arguments and pre-escaping any string or character objects before applying the format strings. This brought me back to another problem I was having earlier, in trying to iterate an argument list of different types (NSString, int etc), like NSLog does. I think I found that it **is** impossible (or at least really difficult) to do this, and the reason NSLog can is that it knows what types to expect through the format specifiers (%@, %i etc).

I realize I can actually get the same effect not by escaping the arguments, but by *escaping* the format string itself.

Example:

```
format: "test //italic %@//"
args: "text // more text"
```

Steps:

1. First replace all instances of // with //-TAG-//
2. Apply the arguments
3. Determine where styling applies between //-TAG-//

Obviously //-TAG-// can still be written in the arguments to mess up the styling, however depending on what you use as a replacement, the chances of this happening are essentially zero.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing it in the order of Parse attributes -> Apply arguments..., I
>   could easily solve it the other way but I don't want format arguments
>   to mess with the attributes

Why not simply add an escape-character? From what I understand you run the risk of the example you provided getting messed up if the first string contains a double slash?

```
"key"="test //italic %@// **bold** __underline %d__";
```

if `%@` is `text // more text` that would screw up the formatting.

If so, then simply parse every vararg of the type `NSString` and `char` to make sure that they don't contain any of the characters you reserved for your attributes. If they do, add some escape char before which you remove upon parsing the attributes.

The above example would look like this after applying the arguments:

```
"key"="test //italic text \/\/ more text// **bold** __underline 34__";
```

After which you parse the attributes, same way as before but you ignore characters preceded by `\` and make sure to remove the `\`.

It's a bit of effort but I bet it's a lot less than implementing your own printf-style parser.

Comment: Hey, do you mean potentially go over the arguments before hand and pre-escape any characters before applying then format, and then the styling at the end. I think this may be a viable solution. Another problem I was having was iterating over a list of arguments of different types, say an NSString followed by an int, followed by a float, etc etc, do you know how this could work?

Comment: Yes, precisely. However since only strings and chars can cause issues with the formatting you only need to go over those beforehand, if you have some other reason for doing argument replacement afterwards. Regarding your second question, I'd say that it probably warrants a new question on its own.

Comment: I did, I feel it's simply a different way of doing the same thing as what the author is already doing and that the answer doesn't really add anything. However I'm not sure that it's a valid reason for a down vote so I'll remove it again. (Never mind, too late to do that unless you edit the post :()

Comment: @Rick Well I find it extremely distasteful to downvote someone else's answer.  It smacks of attempting to gain favour for your own answer at the cost of another's answer.  This is backed-up by the fact that you didn't give a reason for the downvote.  And finally your answer doesn't provide much in the way of a solution, given you talk about escaping the markdown text and simply describe how markdown already does it.

Comment: I mentioned reasons both here and in the comments to your answer. I also offered to remove the down vote, however at that point it was too late. My answer provides a solution to the problem on a conceptual basis, as the author isn's using MD it doesn't matter what MD does or doesn't do. To me this was the obvious solution, solving both issues presented in the question.

Comment: @Rick Thanks for your solution, I was able to tweak the general idea into something that works perfect in my situation :)

Comment: @Rick Yeah I managed to solve the whole lot (this was a small problem in a bigger picture)

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSAttributedString (AttributedFormat)
- (instancetype)initWithFormat:(NSAttributedString *)attrFormat, ...;
- (instancetype)initWithFormat:(NSAttributedString *)attrFormat arguments:(va_list)arguments;
@end

@implementation NSAttributedString (AttributedFormat)

- (instancetype)initWithFormat:(NSAttributedString *)attrFormat, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, attrFormat);
    self = [self initWithFormat:attrFormat arguments:args];
    va_end(args);
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFormat:(NSAttributedString *)attrFormat arguments:(va_list)arguments {
    NSRegularExpression *regex;
    regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern: @"(%.*?[@%dDuUxXoOfeEgGccsSpaAF])"
                                                 options: 0
                                                   error: nil];
    NSString *format = attrFormat.string;
    format = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString: format
                                             options: 0
                                               range: NSMakeRange(0, format.length)
                                        withTemplate: @"\0$1\0"];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arguments];
    NSMutableArray *f_comps = [format componentsSeparatedByString:@"\0"].mutableCopy;
    NSMutableArray *r_comps = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@"\0"].mutableCopy;

    NSMutableAttributedString *output = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    __block int consumed_length = 0;

    [attrFormat enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrFormat.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        NSMutableString *substr = [NSMutableString string];
        while(f_comps.count > 0 && NSMaxRange(range) >= consumed_length + [(NSString *)f_comps[0] length]){
            NSString *f_str = f_comps[0];
            NSString *r_str = r_comps[0];
            [substr appendString:r_str];
            [f_comps removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [r_comps removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            consumed_length += f_str.length;
        }

        NSUInteger idx = NSMaxRange(range) - consumed_length;
        if(f_comps.count > 0 && idx > 0) {
            NSString *f_str = f_comps[0];

            NSString *leading = [f_str substringToIndex:idx];
            [substr appendString:leading];

            NSString *trailing = [f_str substringFromIndex:idx];
            [f_comps replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trailing];
            [r_comps replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trailing];
            consumed_length += idx;
        }
        [output appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:substr attributes:attrs]];
    }];

    return [self initWithAttributedString:output];
}
@end
```

Usage example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *fmt = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test: "];
[fmt appendAttributedString: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Some%%string"
                                                             attributes: @{
                                                                           NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]
                                                                           }]];
[fmt appendAttributedString: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"bold %@ template %.3f %d"
                                                             attributes: @{
                                                                           NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20],
                                                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]
                                                                           }]];
[fmt appendAttributedString: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"%@ blah blah blah"
                                                             attributes: @{
                                                                           NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16],
                                                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor]
                                                                           }]];

NSAttributedString *result = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFormat:fmt, @"[foo]", 1.23, 56, @"[[bar]]"];
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Maybe this still have some bugs, but it should work in most cases.

---

```
(%.*?[@%dDuUxXoOfeEgGccsSpaAF])
```

This regex matches ["Format Specifiers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1). specifier begin with `%` and end with listed characters. and may have some modifiers between them. It's not perfect, for example this illegal format `"%__s"` should be ignored but my regex matches this whole string. but as long as the specifier is legal one, it should works.

My code matches it, and insert delimiters around the specifiers:

```
I'm %s.
I'm <delimiter>%s<delimiter>.
```

I use `\0` as a delimiter.

```
I'm \0%s\0.
```

then interpolate it.

```
I'm \0rintaro\0.
```

then split the format and the result with the delimiter:

```
f_comps: ["I'm ", "%s", "."]
r_comps: ["I'm ", "rintaro", "."]
```

Here, total string length of `f_comps` is exact the same as original attributed format. Then, iterate the attributes with `enumerateAttributesInRange`, we can apply the attributes to the results.

I'm sorry but it's too hard to explain the jobs inside `enumerateAttributesInRange`, with my poor English skills :)

Comment: Are you able to explain the regex and componentsSeparatedByString in more depth? From what I see it's splitting where the specifiers are, not sure what's happening after there. Also I'm still concerned about doing my own specifier implementation, but it may be useful for somebody else.